# Nokia N97 realted to orientation

Tags: java-me, jsr179

Myself shweta dodiya.I am facing problem with nokia N97 related to change orientation for my game application.
I am using J2me technology.I want to pause my application when i open my slider.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slide in/out event in N97 using J2me](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416472/slide-in-out-event-in-n97-using-j2me)

Comment: If you have the canvas instance on which you are drawing the game (current displayable), you need to override its method: `public void sizeChanged(int w, int h)` and in it check is the orientation landscape, if so, draw PAUSE screen and pause the game, if not, redraw the game...

Comment: YOU CAN MARK MY ANSWER AS THE ACCEPTED ONE... I am not going to help you any more if you are ignoring my effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what code are you using, or are you using Canvas to draw the game on screen, or some other API that does that for you...

If you have something like this `GameScreen extends Canvas` and you use `GameScreen` object to draw and display the game, you need to add an override to `sizeChanged` method to it and check the new width (w) and the new height (h) of the GameScreen, and do the things you want in regards to that:

```
public void sizeChanged(int w, int h)
{
    if(h > w)  //NORMAL
    {
        drawGame();
        if(paused) resumeGame();            
    }
    else  //LANDSCAPE
    {
        pauseGame();
        drawPauseScreen();
    }
}
```

This is a simple pseudo code, I hope you are getting the point. If statement is checking the relation between new width and the new height. If the phone is in landscape mode, H is less then W...

Comment: hello, I have one another problem related to nokia N97 only.I want to hide my Game and Navigation keys.I had used the the steps in my mobile to hide the key it is working The steps are :--but i wants do it programmatic.